# Why does redirection fail when passing through ssh, sudo and sh?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sudo, redirection

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr), I know that I have to do

```
sudo sh -c 'ls -hal /root/ > /root/test.out'
```

to avoid the "Permission denied" error.

But when I do

```
ssh hostname sudo sh -c 'ls -hal /root/ > /root/test.out'
```

from another machine, I get

```
bash: /root/test.out: Permission denied
```

Why? And how can I get this to work?

**Edit**: There is the line

```
Defaults:<username>    !requiretty
```

before

```
<username> ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL
```

in `/etc/sudoers`.

I can do

```
ssh remote-machine 'sudo ls /'
```

without any problem.
So I don't think it is a tty problem.
Adding -t does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the quotes are interpreted and stripped by the local shell, not the remote one; you need one extra level:

`ssh host sudo sh -c '"ls -hal /root/ > /root/test.out"'`

The local shell will consume one level of quoting - the single quotes get "used up" here, ssh will get the arguments `host`, `sudo`, `sh`, `-c`, and `"ls -hal /root/ > /root/test.out"`.

The remote shell consumes the next layer - the double quotes - and calls `sudo` with `sh`, `-c`, and `ls -hal /root/ > /root/test.out`.

Finally, the `sh` instance (running as root) is called with `-c` and `ls -hal /root/ > /root/test.out` - and parses that single argument as a normal commandline, evaluating the redirection.

To watch all of this, on the target system, try running `sudo strace -f -e execve -p $(cat /var/run/sshd.pid)`.

Comment: what if I want to have `$1` inside the quotes?